# Проверка содержит ли переменная текст

Tags: php

```
if ($gem_cost !='')
```

Насколько я помню, делается как-то так. Проверьте меня, обычное текстовое поле.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Здравствуйте, несколько способов есть, например:
**Первый способ:**

```
 if(!isset($get_cost))  
      echo "Переменная пустая";
```

**Второй способ**

```
   if(empty($get_cost))
          echo "Переменная пустая";
```

**Третий способ (только для целых чисел)**

```
if((int)$get_cost == 0)
     echo "Переменная пустая или содержит не целое число";
```

**Четвертый способ**

```
if(strlen($get_cost) == 0) 
   echo "Переменная пустая";
```

**Пятый способ**

```
 if(!$get_cost)
     echo "Переменная пустая";
```

**Шестой способ**

```
 if($get_cost == false)
         echo "Переменная пустая";
```

**Седьмой способ**

```
 if($get_cost != '')
         echo "Переменная пустая";
```

Comment: ты джедай.Тебе книги нужно писать

Comment: isset() используешь неверно - это проверка на существование переменной, а не на ее значение. 
$a = '';
isset($a) == true;

Подходит только, если значение переменной - NULL.

$a = null;
isset($a) == false;

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($gem_cost))
{
    echo "Переменная не содержит текст";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($gem_cost == '')
{
echo "Переменная пустая";
}
else
{
echo "Переменная не пустая, и содержит текст: ".$gem_cost;
}
?>
```